# NHibernate left join a unrelated entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have two entities:

```
Konto
- Id
- MwstId

Mwst
- Id
- Code
```

Both entities are correct mapped in Nhibernate - but the Relation between Konto.MwstId -> Mwst.Id is not mapped. I cannot add this map because of structure restrictions.

Now, I try to implement the following Query with NHibernate-QueryOver-API:

```
select * from Konto k left outer join Mwst m on k.MwstId = m.Id
```

I have tried several approaches, but without any success.

Comment: You can use cross join, which is available only with HQL queries. But that would do what you need as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with Criteria/QueryOver or with SQL. If you want to bring back entities with a SQL query, use a syntax like this:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("select {k.*} from Konto k ...").AddEntity("k", typeof(Konto)).List<Konto>();
```